# 2-dimensional random walk, covariance

Tags: probability, statistics

Let $X_1, \ldots X_n \sim N \left( \left[ \begin{array}{c}
0  \\
0  \end{array} \right], \left[ \begin{array}{cc}
1 & \rho\\
\rho & 1\end{array} \right] \right), S_n = \sum \limits_{i = 1}^n X_i$.

If we had one dimensional random walk, the variance is $\sigma^2n$. But, how to compute covariance matrix of $S_n$ in 2-dimensional case?

Comment: Assuming the $X_i$'s are independent, the covariance of $S_n$ is simply $\begin{bmatrix}n&n\rho\\n\rho&n\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: But $X_i^1$ and $X_j^2$ are dependent, so we can't say that $X_i$ and $X_j$ are independent.

Comment: $cov(S_n^1, S_n^2) = cov(\sum X_i^1, \sum X_j^2)$. It is equal to $n \rho$ if $cov(X_i^1, X_j^2) = 0$, but generally it is not true.

Comment: You are assuming $X_i$'s are i.i.d, right? Otherwise we don't have enough information

Comment: $X_i$ are iid, but $X_i^1$ and $X_j^2$ could be dependent

Comment: Imagine $A$ and $B$ are independent, but the first element of $A$ is dependent on the second element of $B$, how can be that?

Answer (score 0):

$S_n^1 = \sum X_i^1, S_n^2 = \sum X_i^2$, since they are both of zero expectation
$$cov(S_n^1, S_n^1) = E((\sum X_i^1)^2) = \sum E((X_i^1)^2) = n$$
$$cov(S_n^1, S_n^2) = E((\sum X_i^1)(\sum X_i^2)) = \sum E(X_i^1X_i^2) = n\rho$$

Similarly for $cov(S_n^2, S_n^2)$.

Comment: why $E((\sum X_i^1)(\sum X_i^2)) = \sum E(X_i^1X_i^2)$? $cov(X_i^1, X_j^2) \ne 0$

Comment: If $i\neq j$, $E(X_i^1 X_j^2) = 0$. The covariance matrix you give is for dependence between $X_i^1, X_i^2$ with the same $i$, not for different $X_i, X_j$